# How to show values repeatedly in the same textbox?

Tags: android, frequency-analysis

At first I should appologize if code below looks horrible and not formatted correctly. I don't know much about programming, so I took pieces of programs from different sources and just put them together.

In app I'd like to display frequency (using zero crossing method) of sound from phone mic. 
When I running app it shows frequency once but doesn't updating it.

1) Can you please help me to find solution for displaying frequency values repeatedly in the same textbox (or in more appropriate widget on the screen)?

*2) Is it possible to make this app without buttons. I mean is that app shows frequency right after it starts?*SOLVED

Thank You!

```
package alar.alar.com.frequencyFreq;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 8000;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    public AudioRecord recorder = null;
    int numCrossing, p;
    short audioData[];
    public int frequency;
    public boolean recording;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                RECORDER_SAMPLERATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING, bufferSize);

        recorder.startRecording();
        recording = true;
        audioData = new short[bufferSize];
            recorder.read(audioData, 0, bufferSize);
            numCrossing = 0;

            for (p = 0; p < bufferSize - 1; p++) {
                if ((audioData[p] > 0 && audioData[p + 1] <= 0) ||
                        (audioData[p] < 0 && audioData[p + 1] >= 0)) {
                    numCrossing++;
                }
            }

            frequency = (8000 / bufferSize) * (numCrossing / 2);

            TextView textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(frequency));

        }//onCreate
    }//activity
```

Comment: for the buttons question,  call startRecording method inside onCreate , hope it helps

Comment: you have to update your app every second,  now I can't write code, search for update android app every second

Comment: Thank you Andrea! Buttons question I resolved so I updated the code.

Comment: I tried this app updating thing, but it doesn't help or I'm using it in wrong way. It seems that I need some kind of loop somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    private Timer timer; 
private TimerTask timerTask; 
public void onPause(){ super.onPause();
 timer.cancel(); 
} public void onResume(){
 super.onResume(); 
try { 
timer = new Timer(); timerTask = new TimerTask() { 
@Override 
public void run() { 
//your method } 
};
 timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); } catch (IllegalStateException e){ android.util.Log.i("Damn", "resume error"); } }
```